# Последовательное использование lock()

Tags: c#, многопоточность

```
object Lock_s1 = new object();
object Lock_s2 = new object();
object Lock_s3 = new object();

async void P1()
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        lock (Lock_s1) Действие_1;
    });
}

async void P2()
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        lock (Lock_s2) Действие_2;
    });
}

async void P3()
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        lock (Lock_s3) Действие_3;
    });
}

async void P4()
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        lock (Lock_s1) lock (Lock_s2) lock (Lock_s3)
                {
                    Действия_4;
                }
    });
}
```

В моем случае нужно, чтоб процедуры P1,P2,P3 могли пересекаться между собой.

Но не с процедурой P4.

Этот код работает, но слишком много lock в void P4, особенно если блокировать нужно будет не 3 объекта а 50.. 500..

Comment: Опишите, какую задачу решаете и что делают действия.

Comment: @tym32167 работа с переменными, массивами, листами... Пытался массив object[] запихать в lock, но так не работает

Comment: Опишите еще подробнее :) есть готовые решения для некоторых типовых задач, тот же ReaderWriterLock, может быть что-то из них подойдет - но надо, чтобы другие участники поняли, что именно у вас за задача.

Comment: Как описал в вопросе, все так и есть. Чтоб много потоков могли пересекаться между собой, но когда работает один определенный P4, они замолкали.

Comment: Это делается через стандартный [ReaderWriterLockSlim](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim?view=netframework-4.8). P4 - writer, все остальные - reader. Reader-ы могут работать одновременно друг с другом, writer может работать только один, причем ридеры будут его ждать.

Comment: @PashaPash да, нужно разобраться с этим ReaderWriterLockSlim

Answer (score 0):

Так работает вроде:

```
public static void ololok(int k)
{
    lock (obj_massiv[k-1])
    {
        if (k == 0) Действие;
        else ololok(--k);
    }
}
```

Где `k` - размер массива локов.

Comment: простите за предвзятость, но это вы поставили минус (мне важен не минус, а за что)?

Answer (score 0):

## Решение

### Дисклеймер

Вы, конечно, можете использовать блокировку объекта, или создать массив `syncRoot`'ов, но это не эффективно. Совсем! Мой алгоритм, конечно, сложен, но он довольно эффективен. Кода много, но сам по себе он средней сложности, все сложные или не типовые моменты я прокомментировал; если что-то не понятно, welcome в комментарии.

Ссылки на доп. инфу по спанам и памяти: ссылки #1,2

### Абстракция

Для создания такого (concurrent) массива (я буду использовать fixed-size массив) нам понадобятся:

- `Memory<T>` – сам массив
- `Memory<Synchronizer>` – массив синхронизаторов. Пока не понятно, каких именно
- `syncR, syncW` – флаги, указывающие, нужно ли синхронизировать ввод/вывод

### Реализация

#### Синхронизатор

В качестве синхронизатора мы будет использовать `SpinLocker` (не путать со `SpinLock`). Он у нас особенный. Он запоминает id блокирующего потока. Если оно совпадает, избегает dead-lock'а, иначе ждёт освобождения locker'а. Это оптимизированная версия обычного `Monitor`. Вы, конечно, можете использовать и его, но это *очень* неэффективно, т. к. создаёт много блоков синхронизации и много объектов, а в нашем `SpinLocker` только 1 `int` – я вас предупредил.

*SpinLocker.cs*

```
public struct SpinLocker
{
    int threadId;

    public static bool TryLock(ref SpinLocker locker, int threadId) =>
        Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref locker.threadId, threadId, 0) == 0;
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static void Lock(ref SpinLocker locker, int threadId)
    {
        while (!TryLock(ref locker, threadId)) { }
    }
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static void Lock(ref SpinLocker locker)
    {
        var curThreadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;

        Lock(ref locker, curThreadId);
    }
    public static void Unlock(ref SpinLocker locker) => Volatile.Write(ref locker.threadId, 0);

    // прочие методы (приведение к `int`, потокобезопасное прочтение, ...) пропущены
}
```

Реализация сверх оптимизирована. Самые главные методы: `TryLock`, `Lock` (обе перегрузки) и `Unlock` – сфокусируйте свой внимание на них.

#### Опции синхронизации

*SynchronizationOptions.cs*

```
[Flags]
public enum SynchronizationOptions
{
    NonSynchronized = 0x0,
    SynchronizedReading = 0x1,
    SynchronizedWriting = 0x2,
    FullySynchronized = SynchronizedReading | SychronizedWriting
}
```

*ConcurrentServices.cs*

```
public static partial ConcurrentServices
{
    public static void Check(this SynchronizationOptions synchronizationOptions)
    {
        const SynchronizationOptions maxOpt = SynchronizationOptions.FullySynchronized;

        if (synchronizationOptions < 0 || synchronizationOptions > maxOpt)
            /*throw*/;
    }
}
```

Тут ничего лишнего – думаю, всё понятно.

#### Сам массив

Вот мы и подобрались к массиву. Проще сперва написать, а потом объяснить.

*ConcurrentArray.cs*

```
public class ConcurrentArray<T> : IList<T>
{
    public const SynchronizationOptions DefaultSynchronizationOptions = SynchronizationOptions.SynchronizedWriting;

    readonly Memory<T> items;
    readonly Memory<SpinLocker> itemLockers;
    readonly bool syncR, syncW;

    public T this[Index index]
    {
        get
        {
            var offset = index.GetOffset(Length);

            if (syncR) LockItem(index);

            var item = Items[offset];

            if (syncR) UnlockItem(index);

            return item;
        }
        set
        {
            var offset = index.GetOffset(Length);

            if (syncW) LockItem(index);

            Items[offset] = value;

            if (syncW) UnlockItem(index);
        }
    }
    public int Length => items.Length; // можно не синхронизировать, т. к. только чтение
    public SynchronizationOptions SynchronizationOptions { get; } // можно не синхронизировать, по аналогии

    public ConcurrentArray(Memory<T> buffer, SynchronizationOptions synchronizationOptions = DefaultSynchronizationOptions)
    {
        synchronizationOptions.Check();

        items = buffer;
        itemLockers = new SpinLocker[Length];
        SynchronizationOptions = synchronizationOptions;
        syncR = (SynchronizationOptions & SynchronizationOptions.SynchronizedReading) != 0;
        syncW = (SynchronizationOptions & SynchronizationOptions.SynchronizedWriting) != 0;
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    internal void LockItem(Index index) // почему `internal` узнаете позже
    {
        var offset = index.GetOffset(Length);

        SpinLocker.Lock(ref itemLockers.Span[offset]);
    }
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    void UnlockItem(Index index)
    {
        var offset = index.GetOffset(Length);

        SpinLocker.Unlock(ref itemLockers.Span[offset]);
    }

    // прочие члены пропущены...
}
```

Ну вот казалось бы и всё? Да, этот массив работает, но есть 1 "но". Если вы попытаетесь его протестировать, скажем, на инкременте (10 потоков одновременно увеличивают значение 1-го элемента массива типа `int` до 1 000 000 каждый поток), то вы столкнётесь с неприятным результатом. Пока вы увеличиваете значение, 1-2 потока его уже увеличили, и вы присваиваете "устаревшее" значение, таким образом вы получаете значение намного меньше ожидаемого. Как с этим бороться?

Ответ прост, нужно создать disposable `struct`. При его создании элемент блокируется, а при его disposing'е – освобождается. Но есть 1 "но". Это не просто `struct`, а `ref struct`, т. к. нам нужно, чтобы данный объект не передавали в другие потоки, что сильно усложняет задачу. Но я опять же нашёл решение, немного жёсткое, но что поделать.

#### `ConcurrentItemRef`

Это потокобезопасная ссылка на элемент. Причём буквально это управляемая GC ссылка на элемент. Пара типов-helper'ов.

**Ссылки**

*Ref.cs*

```
public readonly ref struct Ref<T>
{
    public static Ref<T> Null => default;

    readonly Span<T> targetWrapper;

    [NotNull] // возврат не null
    public ref T Target
    {
        get
        {
            if (IsNull) throw new NullReferenceException();

            return ref MemoryMarshal.GetReference(targetWrapper);
        }
    }
    public bool IsNull => targetWrapper.IsEmpty;
    public bool NotNull => !IsNull;

    public Ref([AllowNull] /*может быть null*/ ref T target)
    {
        targetWrapper = target is null ? default : MemoryMarshal.CreateSpan(ref target, 1);
    }

    public static Ref<T> Wrap([AllowNull] ref T target) => new Ref<T>(ref target);
    public static Ref<T> GetRef(Span<T> buffer) => buffer.IsEmpty ? default :
        new Ref<T>(ref MemoryMarshal.GetReference(buffer));
    public bool TryGetTarget([MaybeNullWhen(false)] out T target)
    {
        target = default!;

        if (IsNull) return false;

        target = ref MemoryMarshal.GetReference(targetWrapper);

        return true;
    }

    // прочие члены пропущены...
}
```

*ReadOnlyRef.cs*

```
public readonly ref struct ReadOnlyRef<T>
{
    public static Ref<T> Null => default;

    readonly ReadOnlySpan<T> targetWrapper;

    [NotNull]
    public readonly ref T Target
    {
        get
        {
            if (IsNull) throw new NullReferenceException();

            return ref MemoryMarshal.GetReference(targetWrapper);
        }
    }
    public bool IsNull => targetWrapper.IsEmpty;
    public bool NotNull => !IsNull;

    public ReadOnlyRef([AllowNull] in T target)
    {
        targetWrapper = target is null ? default : MemoryMarshal.CreateSpan(ref Unsafe.AsRef(in target), 1);
    }

    public static ReadOnlyRef<T> Wrap([AllowNull] in T target) => new ReadOnlyRef<T>(in target);
    public static ReadOnlyRef<T> GetRef(ReadOnlySpan<T> buffer) => buffer.IsEmpty ? default :
        new ReadOnlyRef<T>(in MemoryMarshal.GetReference(buffer));
    public bool TryGetTarget([MaybeNullWhen(false)] out T target)
    {
        target = default!;

        if (IsNull) return false;

        target = MemoryMarshal.GetReference(targetWrapper);

        return true;
    }

    // прочие члены пропущены...
}
```

Смотрите в чём дело. Нам в будущем понадобится хранить ссылку на класс, но это `ref struct` (ссылка #3). Как быть? Обернуть её в `Span` (ссылка #3)! Ссылка – это `Span` с длиной 1, т. е. `ref struct`. Мы его обернули в тип `Ref`/`ReadOnlyRef`, чтоб просто лучше выглядело.

**Сама "ссылка на элемент"**

*ConcurrentArray.cs*

```
public class ConcurrentArray<T> : IList<T>
{
    <...>

    readonly ConcurrentItemRef<T>.ReleaseCallback releaseCallback;

    public ConcurrentArray(<...>)
    {
        <...>

        releaseCallback = UnlockItem;
    }

    internal Memory<T> AsMemory() => items; // возвращает несинхронизированную память, поэтому `internal`
    public ConcurrentItemRef<T> CreateItemRef(Index index) => new ConcurrentItemRef<T>(this, index);

    <...>
}
```

*ConcurrentItemRef.cs*

```
public ref struct ConcurrentItemRef<T>
{
    Ref<T> valueRef; // ссылка на элемент
    ReadOnlyRef<ReleaseCallback> releaseCallbackRef; // ссылка на release callback
    readonly int offset; // смещение нашего элемента

    public ref T Value
    {
        get
        {
            ThrowIfReleased();

            return ref valueRef.Target;
        }
    }
    bool IsReleased => valueRef.IsNull;

    internal ConcurrentItemRef(ConcurrentArray<T> array, Index index)
    {
        if (array == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("array");

        offset = index.GetOffset(array.Length);
        valueRef = Ref<T>.GetRef(array.AsMemory().Slice(offset, 1).Span);
        releaseCallbackRef = ReadOnlyRef<ReleaseCallback>.Wrap(in array.releaseCallback);

        array.LockItem(index); // вот и пригодился нам `internal` `LockItem`
    }

    public void Release()
    {
        if (IsReleased) return;

        if (releaseCallbackRef.TryGetTarget(out var releaseCallback))
        {
            releaseCallback.Invoke(offset);

            releaseCallbackRef = default;
        }

        valueRef = default;
    }
    public void Dispose() => Release();
    void ThrowIfReleased()
    {
        if (IsReleased) throw new InvalidOperationException("This concurrent item ref is released");
    }

    internal delegate void ReleaseCallback(Index offset);
}
```

Вы меня, наверно, спросите: "Зачем нам брать и создавать кокой-то release callback, если можно просто запихнуть массив?" Нет, нельзя. Т. к. `Ref` – это ссылка на класс, а массив – это просто класс, т. е. нам где-то нужно инициализировать ссылку на массив, а т. к. единственное место где это без ошибки компиляции можно сделать – стек (т. е. нигде, т. к. по окончанию выполнения метода мы сразу же потеряет доступ к ссылке), то мы не можем передать его на прямую, да и это играет на расширяемости (можно создать, например, `ConcurrencyList`, который тоже их [`ConcurrentcyItemRef`] будет возвращать).

### Тестирование

Наконец-то тестирование всего этого кода! Это тот самый инкремент.

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
    const int taskCount = 5;

    var array = new ConcurrentArray<int>(1);
    var tasks = new Task[taskCount];

    for (var i = 0; i < taskCount; i++)
        tasks[i] = CountAsync(array, 0);

    Task.WhenAll(tasks).Wait();

    Assert.AreEqual(5_000_000, array[0]);
}
async Task CountAsync(ConcurrentArray<int> array, Index index)
{
    await Task.CompletedTask.ConfigureAwait(false); // для аснихронности (ссылки #4,5)

    for (var i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++)
        using (var itemRef = array.CreateItemRef(index))
            itemRef.Value++;
}
```

Думаю, вы понимаете результат.

## Ссылки

- [Ссылка #1](https://habr.com/ru/post/352716/) – Span, Memory и ReadOnlyMemory
- [Ссылка #2](https://habr.com/ru/company/clrium/blog/420051/) – Новинки C# 7.2: Span и Memory
- [Ссылка #3](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1147) – Github issue: Могут ли `ref struct` хранить `ref fields` (en)
- [Ссылка #4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fi_N_ghu4Ug) – Видео урок: `async`/`await`
- [Ссылка #5](https://habr.com/ru/post/482354/) – ConfigureAwait: Часто задаваемые вопросы

Comment: Если что то не понятно, задавайте вопросы.

Comment: Ровно 9 экранов))